# Prove that $\sup(AB) = \sup(A)\cdot \sup(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A, B \subset (0, \infty)$ be non-empty and bounded from above. Construct the
set of products:

$P(AB) = \{x \in (0, \infty)| \exists a \in A, \exists b \in B  \text{ such that }x = ab\}$.

Show that $\sup\big(P(AB)\big) = \sup(A)\cdot \sup(B)$

---

My initial idea is to show $\leq$ and $\geq$. I have some vague ideas, but I have a lot of blind spots with regards to inequalities, so I would be very grateful for help and explanations.

Comment: See these three threads: [Link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46738/product-of-sets-and-supremum) and [Link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003659/supremum-of-the-product-of-sets) and [Link 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064502/proving-supremum-of-product-set-of-nonnegative-real-numbers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Product of sets and supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46738/product-of-sets-and-supremum)